# Is it possible to minimise applications using the Unity bar?

Tags: 10.10, unity

I quite Unity but it seems like odd behaviour that clicking on the icon "focusses" the application instead of minimising it when it's already focussed.

Comment: Note that it's possible this will change in 11.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've made a script to workaround this issue.
See this working [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=itaH9Ghdc8I).

**Instructions**

**1)** We will need [XDoTool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xdotool) and [Compiz](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager).

You can install these from the *Ubuntu Software Center* or by clicking [here (xdotool)](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xdotool) and [here (Compiz)](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager)

**2)** Open Compiz (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type `ccsm` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

**3)** Go to Commands and add `~/.minimize` to one command:

[image]

**4)** Then go to Button Binding and make a shortcut for it.

[image]

**5)** Make a file named .minimize at your home folder (`gedit ~/.minimize`). Paste this and save:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# by desgua
# version 0.1.3 - May 06 2011
# To minimize with unity Launcher
##################################
import os
import wnck
import gtk
stream = os.popen("xdotool click --clearmodifiers 1")
screen = wnck.screen_get_default()

while gtk.events_pending():
    gtk.main_iteration()

windows = screen.get_windows()
active_app = screen.get_active_window().get_application()

for w in windows:
    if w.get_application() == active_app:
        w.minimize()
```

**6)** Make it executable  ([Here's how to do that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35478/how-do-i-mark-a-file-as-executable-via-a-gui/35528#35528)).

**7)** Enjoy!  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to minimize a focused application by clicking on the launcher icon in the launcher bar (= panel on the left).

When you do this, you initiate the "app expose" function, which will give you an overview of all running instances of the focused application. Eg., when a terminal is focused and you have four terminals opened, then clicking on the launcher would give you this:

[image]

This also happens with only one instance open - seems odd, but changing the click behavior for one use case would introduce (unwanted) inconsistency. However, I do not know if it's planned to fundamentally change all of this for Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: Wow, where did that themed Unity come from?!