# How do I mark a file as executable via a GUI?

Tags: nautilus, gui, executable

How do I mark a file as executable using a graphical interface (GUI)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Simple Permissions Tab (default)

First, right click on your file and choose 'Properties'.

[image]

Switch to the 'Permissions' tab and then simply check the box that says 'Allow executing file as program'.

[image]

Comment: Very good! I miss that simple layout in my system... sometimes...

Comment: @GeppettvsD'Constanzo: I prefer the advanced one for the control it gives

Comment: You can get Tommy's permissions dialog with `gconftool --set "/apps/nautilus/preferences/show_advanced_permissions" --type=boolean false`

Comment: @pydave - Brilliant. Thanks very much for the `gconftool` heads up.

Answer (score 7):

### Advanced Permissions Tab

Just right click the file, choose "Properties" (at the very bottom), click in the "Permissions" Tab and add the executable option to the file, which may differ from this in the screenshot in a certain cases.

[image]

Sometimes I have found a "Make this file executable" option in certain kind of files.

You should be the owner of the file in order to perform this without a hassle. Take a look at this in order to change file/folder ownership: [General Rules for dealing with File Permissions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35367/general-rules-for-dealing-with-file-permissions/35384#35384)

Good luck!

Comment: If you are in Ubuntu 10.10, that permissions tab would look like this: http://i.imgur.com/JfV5H.png

Comment: It is weird. I am on Ubuntu 10.10 and my permissions tab looks like I have placed in the screenshot. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Tommy Just make that a separate answer that way we have them both up front!

Comment: How your permissions tab looks depends on a gconf key; Tommy's screenshot shows the default, simple variant for "normal" end users, Geppettvs's screenshot shows the "technical" variant for advanced users.

Comment: You can get Geppettvs's permissions dialog with `gconftool --set "/apps/nautilus/preferences/show_advanced_permissions" --type=boolean true`

Comment: Oh! good! thank you pydave :D This information is useful for me! I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

There two ways (3 in a sense) to do this. Since Geppettvs and Tommy covered two of them already, I will cover the other.

Open the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> dialogue (run dialogue) and type:

`chmod +x /path/to_file/and/name_of_file` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If the file is in a folder you cannot access, use:

`gksu chmod +x /path/to_file/and/name_of_file` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>

Comment: In order not to experience problems with this command you may wish to sudo the command.

Comment: @GeppettvsD'Constanzo: true; I will update my answer

Comment: @roland: using "sudo" unnecessarily can endanger your system. Before using "sudo", make sure you really need it

Comment: Hey! teach me how to make my text to become a text in a box like your "enter" text... please!

Comment: @Geppettvs Just type your text in <kbd>like this</kbd> :)

Comment: :o that easy... haha Thank you very much @Kaustubh P!

Comment: @crucifiedsoul: I already pointed out that they should do that only if they don't have write permissions on the file.

Comment: This is not really via a "graphical interface" (GUI) as requested by the OP. It's a command. You could just as well use a terminal and argue that a terminal is also a GUI. Hey, `gnome-terminal` is written using GTK 3 ;)