# Are there any existing apps similar to GNOME 3's chat popup/respond box?

Tags: unity, software-recommendation

In general, I prefer Unity to Gnome Shell, but the latter's chat popup and inline responder thing (video here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lepXx1kDelo) is more or less a killer app for me and is the only thing preventing me from switching to Unity.

Are there any existing apps/plugins that offer similar functionality that can be used in Unity?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is my Pidgin Show Conversation script alpha 0.1.2. It is not perfect, but has functionality.
It works well with Pidgin. See this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OR03nCkbFwM).

obs.: if you are lazy you can just run this at terminal and skip to step "5"

```
sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get install xdotool compizconfig-settings-manager && cd ~/ && wget http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4098082/.pidginfocus.sh && sudo chmod +x ~/.pidginfocus.sh
```

---

**1)** We will need [XDoTool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xdotool) and [Compiz](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager).

You can install these from the software center (or by [clicking here](http://apt.marcoceppi.com/p/xdotool,compizconfig-settings-manager))

**2)** Make a file `.pidginfocus.sh` in your home folder.

**3)** Paste this into it:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# by desgua
#
# To focus at conversation when the mouse is at botton
while [ "$var1" != "end" ]
do
eval $(xdotool getmouselocation --shell)
echo $Y
if [ "$Y" -gt "680" ] ; then 
    xdotool search --class Pidgin windowmap ; else
    xdotool search --class Pidgin windowunmap ; exit 0 
fi
sleep .5
done
exit 0
```

**4)** Make it executable ([Here's how to do that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35478/how-do-i-mark-a-file-as-executable-via-a-gui/35528#35528))

**5)** Open Compiz (Menu > System > Preferences > CompizConfig Manager)

**6)** Go to Commands and add `~/.pidginfocus.sh` to one command

[image]

**7)** And use Edge Binding (Botton) to run it.

[image]

**8)** Now go to Compiz > Enable Place Windows and set the role conversation to be opened at botton:

*You may need to adjust the numbers according with your screen resolution.*

[image]

Comment: Wow nice, any workaround to get this working with empathy ?

Comment: If you change Pidgin for Empathy at script and role=conversation for class=Empathy it will somehow work. I'm at mobile right now, when I get home I will try to improve this ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The launcher Kupfer http://kaizer.se/wiki/kupfer/ has a pidgin plugin which allows you to begin typing the name of a contact and send them a message all inline of the launcher itself.

This may not be "single use" enough for you and it being a launcher may get in the way, but I guess you could disable all of the other plugins.

Kupfer also has themes now, making it much prettier, http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/kupfer-v206-released-with-improved.html

EDIT:
It is possible to type into an exisiting message.

1. Bring up Kupfer: I have <kbd>F1</kbd> bound to bring up Kupfer.
2. Type the name of the contact
3. <kbd>Tab</kbd> once and you'll be hovering over the open chat launcher.
4. <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> to "Send Message"
5. <kbd>Tab</kbd> again to get to the input box for sending a message.

The launcher has a context dependant number of panels. You can set default actions, which I have.

My standard flow is:
<kbd>F1</kbd> *name* <kbd>Tab</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> *message* <kbd>Return</kbd>.
As even if a chat isn't open this "send message" action does it for you.

Comment: Thanks, that's nice for initiating new conversations but not so much for typing in existing ones.

Comment: It can and its really quick too, check my edit.

Comment: Yeah thanks, it's just that hitting Alt+Tab to switch to the IM window would be quicker.

Comment: That's probably fair. Kupfer remembers the last written items etc. so it normally cuts down on that.
But I can see where you're coming from and at the same time would like to see something similar myself. :)
For me its about not changing workflow (alt-tab breaks my flow).