# Shortcut to resize a window with my custom dimensions?

Tags: 11.04, windows, resize

Is it possible to set my own dimensions for a shortcut so when I activate it the window to resize to my preferred dimensions?

I like the new shortcuts in 11.04 with the numpads, but I would like for example ctrl+alt+num5 to make the window with a lower hight just like the width.

Answer (score 5):

I've made a script for you:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# by desgua
#
# To make the window with a lower hight just like the width.
#############################################################

win=`xdotool getactivewindow`
w=`xwininfo -id $win | grep "Width" | awk '{print $2}'`
#h=`xwininfo -id $win | grep "Height" | awk '{print $2}'`

xdotool windowsize $win $w $w

exit 0
```

**If you're lazy, run this at terminal, and skip to step "6":**

```
cd ~/ && wget dl.dropbox.com/u/4098082/resize.sh && chmod +x ~/resize.sh && ~/resize.sh && rm ~/resize.sh
```

**Step by step instructions:**

**1)** We will need [XDoTool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xdotool) and [Compiz](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager).

(You can install these from the software center (or by [clicking here](http://apt.marcoceppi.com/p/xdotool,compizconfig-settings-manager)))

**2)** Make a file `.resize.sh` in your home folder.

**3)** Paste the above script into it.

**4)** Make it executable  ([Here's how to do that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35478/how-do-i-mark-a-file-as-executable-via-a-gui/35528#35528)).

**5)** Open Compiz (Menu > System > Preferences > CompizConfig Manager)

**6)** Go to Commands and add `~/.resize.sh` to one command

**7)** Then go to Keybindings and make a shortcut for it.