# How do I make a quicklist for umplayer? 

Tags: 11.04, unity, quicklists, mplayer

It's very useful/great multimedia player and more.
Youtube search, watch and saving features, too many file formats that can play etc.

**How can I make [UMPLAYER](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/umplayer-available-in-webupd8-ubuntu.html) quicklist for Unity icon ?**

Note : umplayer -h parameters are complicated, I tryed but...

Comment: what quicklists do you want ?

Comment: Playback options, full screen option etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Copy the original .desktop file to your home folder:

   `cp /usr/share/applications/umplayer.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/`
2. Open that desktop file for editing :

   `gedit ~/.local/share/applications/umplayer.desktop`
3. Add the following at the bottom of the file.

> ```
> X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Play;Pause;Stop;Fullscreen;
>
> [Play Shortcut Group]
> Name=Play
> Exec=umplayer -send-action play
> TargetEnvironment=Unity
>
> [Pause Shortcut Group]
> Name=Pause
> Exec=umplayer -send-action pause
> TargetEnvironment=Unity
>
> [Stop Shortcut Group]
> Name=Stop
> Exec=umplayer -send-action stop
> TargetEnvironment=Unity
>
> [Fullscreen Shortcut Group]
> Name=Fullscreen
> Exec=umplayer -send-action fullscreen
> TargetEnvironment=Unity
> ```

4. Save it and navigate to `~/.local/share/applications/` and [make the umplayer.desktop executable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35478/how-do-i-mark-a-file-as-executable-via-a-gui/35528#35528) and then drag it to the launcher .

[image]