# How do I create a quicklist for Ubuntu Tweak?

Tags: unity, quicklists

I want to create a quicklist for Ubuntu Tweak on my Unity launcher, but I'm having trouble getting started. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The newest versions of Ubuntu Tweak now have a couple of command line parameters which you could exploit to create a quicklist.

By default - ubuntu-tweak has already a quicklist for various features:

[image]

running `ubuntu-tweak -h`:

```
Usage: ubuntu-tweak [options]

Ubuntu Tweak is a tool for Ubuntu that makes it easy to configure your system
and desktop settings.

Options:
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -d, --debug           Generate more debugging information.  [default: False]
  -m MODULE, --module=MODULE
                        Start module directly.  [default: ]
  -f FEATURE, --feature=FEATURE
                        Start feature directly.  [default: ]
```

- Features -

  ```
  ubuntu-tweak -f [feature-name]
  ```

```
   overview
   tweaks
   admins
   janitor
```

- Modules -

  ```
  ubuntu-tweak -m "[ClassName"]
  ```

This is useful if you have any plugins installed.

Thus you can copy `/usr/share/applications/ubuntutweak.desktop` to `~/.local/share/applications` and add any plugins that you may have installed to add to the default quicklist.

See the Linked Question for an example of how to create a quicklist by passing parameters such as a plugin module name to the `ubuntu-tweak` executable.

---

Linked Question:

1. [How do I make a quicklist for umplayer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41668/how-do-i-make-a-quicklist-for-umplayer)