# How to add Quicklists to GTK2 application?

Tags: unity, python, gtk, application-development, webkit

We want to add Quicklists to our app [Nitro](http://nitrotasks.com). However Nitro uses GTK2 as it uses the pywebkitgtk library. As far as I'm aware, we can't use Quicklists because it requires PyGI which requires GTK3 and there is no pywebkitgtk for GTK3.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: not sure I understand your question - "quicklists" refer to the right-click launcher menus as per this Q&A: http://askubuntu.com/questions/63765/how-do-i-create-a-quicklist-for-ubuntu-tweak

Comment: We want to add quicklist support to our app. However it doesn't seem to work in GTK2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [two kinds of quicklist](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/launcher/) entries:

- Static: they only depend on static entries in the `.desktop` files
- Dynamic: they can be created in the program itself and seem to require PyGI.

So for you there seem to be two ways around that:

1. stick with static quicklists
2. write a separate server (very simple, really) that uses gtk3 /PyGI and acts as a bridge between nitro and the launcher.

You have to decide depending on your need, mainly on how much you need the dynamic part. But the second version really is not that hard to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Quicklists doesn't depend on GI or any other library. Like everything else in Unity, it's all DBus behind the scenes.

Comment: most dbus methods used by unity are mainly undocumented (e.g. also the dbus menu). So a bit more information/links to documentation of these would be useful.