# How to run Ubuntu Tweak's janitor automatically?

Tags: command-line, startup, ubuntu-tweak, maintenance

My aim is to have the janitor running at startup, with a pre-configured profile (e.g. clean old packages and empty the browser cache), much like [CCleaner's `/AUTO`](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/faq/installing/can-ccleaner-be-installed-and-run-silently) parameter on Windows.

The [website](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) is lacking any documentation or usage instructions, and I could not find any information on this here on AskUbuntu as well.

I tried, naturally, to start Ubuntu Tweak from the command line, hoping additional API exists that will come through in this (allegedly) simple task.

I only got as far as:

```
ubuntu-tweak -f janitor
```

which is a step in the right direction, but what's still missing is a command for the **clear** action. Is such a command available, or is there any better way of achieving the described behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### for the moment the answer is no...

Let me expand on that statement.

In many ways, your question is similar to this Q&A:

- [How do I create a quicklist for Ubuntu Tweak?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63765/how-do-i-create-a-quicklist-for-ubuntu-tweak/63771#63771)

Ubuntu Tweak only offers (currently) a limited API call for the executable itself.

Therefore - when trying to invoke a Ubuntu-Tweak feature when starting from `startup applications` or via a quick list, you can only use the command line parameters that have been made available.

`ubuntu-tweak -f janitor` is one such feature.  There are no command-line parameters (currently) for what you are seeking to do.

You can test this yourself by running `ubuntu-tweak -h`.  The linked answer above shows the typical result you could expect.

Some programs - once running - expose an interface such as `dbus` that allows you to invoke features via an external program.  Rhythmbox is one such software with its rhythmbox-client which can be called externally.  Ubuntu-tweak unfortunately does not offer the same external interface.

---

What you'll need to do is submit a patch to the author that would add a command-line parameter to do the function you are seeking.

Alternatively - add an externally callable interface such as `dbus` when ubuntu-tweak is actually running.