# Should I increase my partition size when the volume “Filesystem Root” has only few disk space remaining?

Tags: partitioning, memory-usage

My question differs from [The volume "Filesystem Root" has only 533.9 MB disk space remaining](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360969/the-volume-filesystem-root-has-only-533-9-mb-disk-space-remaining), for mine is specific about managing disk space on multiboot devices

From time to time, the system shows this warning message:

[image]

I have a dual-boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. Here's what fdisk shows:

```
mike@mike-thinks:~$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for mike: 
Disk /dev/sda: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc3c0f778

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          2048    1026047    1024000  500M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          1026048 1743806463 1742780416  831G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       1743806464 1782867967   39061504 18,6G 83 Linux
/dev/sda4       1782870014 1953523711  170653698 81,4G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1782870016 1798492159   15622144  7,5G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       1798494208 1953523711  155029504 73,9G 83 Linux

Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: 7,5 GiB, 7998013440 bytes, 15621120 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
mike@mike-thinks:~$ sudo df -h
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                 3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                789M   20M  770M   3% /run
/dev/sda3             19G   17G  418M  98% /
tmpfs                3,9G   58M  3,8G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs                5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda6             73G   63G  6,2G  92% /home
tmpfs                789M   60K  789M   1% /run/user/1000
/home/mike/.Private   73G   63G  6,2G  92% /home/mike
```

What would you advise me to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should definitely increase the size of root from 39GB. Suggest you

A) Make two backups of each partition with data

B) Do

```
sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get clean
```

C) Use gparted after booting from a Live USB and adjust partition sizes to increase the space available to root.