# File system Root has low disk spaceecryptfs

Tags: ecryptfs

I am running dual-boot of Ubuntu 16.04 (encrypted home folder) and Windows 10.  My kernel is also pinned to 4.4.0-112-generic for driver reasons.  Everything has been working fine for months, but recently I started to receive the following message that the fie system has low disk space:

[image]

So I ran `gksudo baobab` from the command line and the Disk Usage Analyzer returned the following:

[image]

According to [instructions found here on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640796/file-system-root-low-disk-space), I have already tried using Ubuntu Tweak to remove old kernels, configs, and clear the apt cache.  This all has no effect.  NOTE: even when I use Nautilus to directly examine the .private folder, I can not find any file large enough to take up all the space on my drive.

How do I solve this problem?

thanks

**UPDATE:**

I deleted over 100 GB of video from my encrypted home folder and I still have the same problem.  Additionally, I now have to boot my Ubuntu from failsafe mode because the normal boot routine can not complete... it simply hangs.

Also I am now receiving (disk) device failure messages when I boot in Recovery Mode (failsafe):

[image]

Appreciate any advice..

Comment: Delete some files from your home directory.  Baobab can't see them since they are encrypted and you ran baobab as root instead of yoruself.

Comment: I deleted over 100 GB from my folder and I still have the problem. I also ran Baobab as myself and still have the problem.