# How to install TeamViewer?

Tags: software-installation, teamviewer

How can I install [TeamViewer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeamViewer) in Ubuntu?

Comment: Please do not post irrelevant links in your question.

Comment: Did something wrong happened? Are you using 32 or 64 bits?

Answer (score 15):

Install the "32-Bit / 64-Bit Multiarch" version. It works on my system flawlessly. Do not install the 64bit only version.

- http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux.aspx

After installing it, to install any extra dependencies, run this command in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

After installation has completed, go to terminal and type teamviewer without Sudo user and it will open up Teaviewer GUI.

Comment: This is the best answer since it includes info about which version to use--which as a user of a 64 bit system is not intuitive.

Answer (score 6):

See page [TeamViewer 9.x, 8.x, 7.x, 6.x, 5.x, 4.x, 3.x, 2.x and 1.x](http://www.teamviewer.com/hi/download/dyngate.aspx) (a download page). Get the .deb file from there and install it with:

```
sudo dpkg -i <filename.deb>
```

Give the password, and it will install. You can also install the .deb file by double-clicking it to open it for installation in the Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 2):

SparkyLinux has a great repository with many apps available. At the time of this writing, you can use their repository to get automatic updates of TeamViewer with apt.

Open a terminal and enter this.

```
sudo su -c "echo 'deb http://sparkylinux.org/repo testing main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install teamviewer
```

All credits go to SparkyLinux for being Awesome.

Comment: Adding the repositories of other Linux distributions is asking for trouble. -1

Comment: This has been -so far- the only way to get teamviewer 13 installed and working on Ubuntu 14.04.5 so... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I use Ubuntu 14.10.

I was unable to install teamviewer_amd64.deb using any suggested methods.

However, I successfully installed Teamviewer using teamviewer_i386.deb.
libjpeg62:i386 is needed as dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the .DEB file from Teamviewer website. Once the download is finished, double click on the file will open ubuntu software center and you will be able to install it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Although they made a "deb" installable package, it seems not to work if you don't have wine installed.

1) Install [Wine](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/wine).

2) Go to [their website](http://www.teamviewer.com/hi/download/index.aspx?os=linux) and download the installer for your computer archicteture (32 or 64 bits).

3) [Make the downloaded file executable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35478/how-do-i-mark-a-file-as-executable-via-a-gui). Then double click it.

If you are feeling lazy, just paste this at terminal and I will do all above for you:

```
sudo apt-get install wine ; rm -R /tmp/teaminstall/ ; mkdir /tmp/teaminstall/ && cd /tmp/teaminstall/ && p=$(uname -p) && if [ $p = "x86_64" ] ; then wget -c http://www.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_linux_x64.deb ; else wget -c http://www.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_linux.deb ; fi ; chmod +x /tmp/teaminstall/teamviewer_linux* && sudo /tmp/teaminstall/teamviewer_linux*
```

Comment: Glad someone reported the Wine issue as well... I am installing on a Ubuntu Linux VPS and the error was that Wine was missing.  Thanks for the code paste, worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Just got TeamViewer 7.0.9350 to install on 64-bit Kubuntu 12.04. Saw at least one bug report and forum discussion where many people seem to be troubled by difficulties in doing so:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1936044

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/synaptic/+bug/971761

I must say it was not as easy as with 32-bit Kubuntu 10.10 where just downloading a Debian package from teamviewer.com and installing it was enough. I was also bothered by error messages such as the following in the first attempt:

Package libc6-i386 is not installed.

The trick was to:

- Edit /etc/apt/sources.list and uncomment the Canonical partner line:

  deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
- Run "apt-get update".
- Run "apt-get -f install".

Finally, the Debian package could be installed as usual by running "dpkg -i teamviewer_linux_x64.deb". Note that all the commands mentioned above need super-user privileges.

Comment: You don't need the 'partner' propsitory for this. in a new debootstrapped environment, it was enough to have 'restricted universe multiverse' enabled, probably less is also enough. Maybe this changed in the past 2.5 years