# Problem while installing Teamviewer

Tags: software-installation, teamviewer

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and I have tried to install Teamviewer by the command line (it says I need superuser privileges) and I have tried the graphical installer but it says it cannot install.

**Update**

I have got Superuser privileges but it says

```
dpkg: error processing archive teamviewer_linux.deb (--install): 
cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing: teamviewer_linux.deb
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install TeamViewer?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/136810/how-to-install-teamviewer). See Raja's answer for how to direct download the TeamViewer .deb file from teamviewer.com and then double click the TeamViewer .deb file to open it for installation in the Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 0):

to get superuser privileges,

first execute in a terminal

```
sudo passwd root
```

you will prompted for a new Unix password. Write it twice(second for confirmation).

Then execute

```
sudo passwd -u root
```

to unlock the account. This should return

```
passwd: password expiry information changed
```

then execute,

```
su
```

and enter in password. you should be in super user privilege mode, then retry your install.

Reverting back

If you want to disable root account in Ubuntu you need to lock the root account by using the following command

```
sudo passwd -l root
```