# How do I mark a file as executable on 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, executable

I just got 13.04 and need to know how to mark a file as executable. So if someone could tell me how that would be great. When I go to permissions the execute thing is not there.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/35478/how-do-i-mark-a-file-as-executable-via-a-gui?rq=1

Comment: Have you tried right clicking the file, clicking 'Properties', then clicking the 'Permissions' tab, and then checking the box 'Allow executing file as program'?  You must be logged in as the same user who owns this file: it will show the owner in the 'Permissions' tab.

Comment: Its says the owner is me and I'm logged on.

Comment: The only things it shows are the read, write, or read and write things.

Comment: Could you take a screenshot, edit your question and add it?

Comment: It says I don't have enough reputation do post the pic.

Comment: Post the screenshot at an image hosting service and put a link in the question. I'll post it into the question for you.

Comment: You should see a check box [like shown here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/buh8g3o7psem1zo/Screenshot%20from%202013-09-18%2016%3A39%3A56.png) to make it executable. Are you seeing something different?

Comment: Hey thanks for the help but I found out what to do with another question.