# Unable to open .x86_64 or .x86 files on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, games

I have recently installed a game and in the game's folder, there's a file with the extension of `x86_64`. I attempted to open said file and recieved this error:

```
Could not display KSP.x86_64
There is no application installed for executable files. Do you want to search for an application to open this file?
```

After that I tried to right click the file and select 'open with other application' and this error message up.

```
No applications available to open KSP.x86_64.
Click Show other application for more options, or find applications online to install new applications.
```

I clicked *'find applications online'* and after a few seconds the following error message showed up.

```
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Python.xdg.Exceptions.ParsingError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 489, in _inline_callbacks
    result = gen.send(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sessioninstaller/core.py", line 1030, in _install_mime_types
    path))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdg/DesktopEntry.py", line 33, in __init__
    self.parse(filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdg/DesktopEntry.py", line 42, in parse
    IniFile.parse(self, file, ["Desktop Entry", "KDE Desktop Entry"])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdg/IniFile.py", line 81, in parse
    raise ParsingError("Invalid line: " + line, filename)
ParsingError: ParsingError in file '/usr/share/app-install/desktop/workrave:workrave.desktop', Invalid line: - RSI (Repetitive Strain Injury) oraz wspomaga rekonwalescencj\u0119
```

How can I open `.x86_64` in Ubuntu 13.04?

Answer (score 3):

You need to [mark the file as executable](https://askubuntu.com/q/35478/176889) then you can double click it and choose "Run in terminal".

#### How to mark a file as executable

1. Right click the file
2. Choose 'Properties'
3. Go to the 'Permissions' tab
4. Tick 'Allow executing this file as a program'
5. Close the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You can either right click on the file, click permissions, and check "Allow executing file as a program", or you can open a terminal and type ./KSP.x86_64 (Note the ./ in front of it.).

Answer (score 1):

## To do it from the command-line:

**Give Execute Permission to file:**

```
chmod +x /path/to/the/file.x86
```

**Go to Files Directory:**

```
cd /path/to/the
```

**Run The File:**

```
./file.x86
```