# automatic start fish shell in terminal window

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, fish

I would like to have separate shortcut at my desktop just for the fish shell,

Having a command like that does not start a window with fish shell :

```
gnome-terminal fish
```

If there is no solution for gnome-terminal , there could be any other window terminal emulator ....

NOTE : I DO NOT WANT TO SET fish as my default shell !

Comment: Make a script to run the command `gnome-terminal -e fish` - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fish

Answer (score 5):

1. Create a new text file on your desktop with these contents:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Fish Shell
   Exec=fish
   Terminal=true
   Type=Application
   Version=1.0
   ```
2. Save the file as `fish.desktop` (in your Desktop).
3. [Mark it as executable.](https://askubuntu.com/q/35478/176889)
4. Double click on the "Fish Shell" file on your Desktop to run the `fish` shell.