# Why bash files are not executed?

Tags: 14.04

Why bash are not executed when I double click on them?

They are executable but they are not executed. Instead they are opened with gedit.

Comment: There is a preference setting in Nautilus which deals with executable files. Perhaps you could try changing it?

Comment: What happens when you execute them in terminal?

Answer (score 1):

I. (GUI method) Right Click the file >> Properties >> Permissions >> (check) Allow executing file as program

[Reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35478/how-do-i-mark-a-file-as-executable-via-a-gui)

OR

II. (Teminal method)

```
chmod +x /path/to/yourscript.sh 
bash /path/to/yourscript.sh
```

[Reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38661/how-do-i-run-sh-files-in-terminal)

Answer (score 0):

Open Nautilus: Edit -> Preferences -> Behavior.

Select "Ask each time" under "Executable Text Files".

Now you can double-click your executable text file in Nautilus to be asked whether to execute or edit your script.